# How do I check what servers my discord bot has joined/is in? discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I want to check what servers my discord bot is in, note I have no idea on how to use discord.client (The bot is written in discord.py)

the code I have tried so far is:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def servers(ctx):
client = discord.Client()
servers = list(client.servers)
await bot.say("Connected on " + str(len(client.servers)) + " servers:")
for x in range(len(servers)):
    await bot.say(" "+servers[x-1].name)
```

(Note that there is proper indentation but stack overflow is not showing it properly)

Comment: You tagged this question  [tag:discord.py-rewrite], but you're using `bot.say`, which is not available in the rewrite branch.  What version of [tag:discord.py] are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
@bot.command()
async def servers(ctx):
  servers = list(bot.guilds)
  await ctx.send(f"Connected on {str(len(servers))} servers:")
  await ctx.send('\n'.join(guild.name for guild in guilds))
```

Comment: It should be noted that in the new version of discord.py, `bot.servers` has been replaced with `bot.guilds`